# Using JavaScript combine Two JSON objects by matching key value and index value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

Ok, I've been racking my brain and trying this in a variety of methods, but I keep running into deadends. I even tried using Angular to do nested ng-repeats to filter down to the properties I needed but that was too heavy on resources.

What I'm trying to do is look up the value of "indices" for each object in the "groups" array, and find the corresponding object in the "person" array by matching the index to the 'indices' value, and then pushing that value to the corresponding object in the 'groups' array.

I'm trying to do this only in JavaScript when a response is returned from an api.

Example below:

```
    var obj = {
    "groups": [
        {
          "name": "GroupA",
          "indices": [
            0
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GroupB",
          "indices": [
            1
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GroupC",
          "indices": [
            2,
            3
          ]
        }
      ],
    "person": [
        {"name": "Archer"},
        {"name": "Lana"},
        {"name": "Mother"},
        {"name": "Barry"}
      ]
  };
```

And this is what I want the final object to look like:

```
 var obj = {
    "groups": [
        {
          "name": "GroupA",
          "indices": [
            0
          ],
        "person": [
          {"name": "Archer"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GroupB",
          "indices": [
            1
          ],
          "person": [
            {"name": "Lana"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GroupC",
          "indices": [
            2,
            3
          ],
          "person": [
            {"name": "Mother"},
            {"name": "Barry"}
          ]
        }
      ]
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `forEach` for the outer loop rather than `map` but it's a matter of style more than substance:

```
 obj.groups.forEach(g => g.person = g.indices.map(i => obj.person[i]))
```

```js
var obj = {
    "groups": [
        {
          "name": "GroupA",
          "indices": [0]
        },
        {
          "name": "GroupB",
          "indices": [ 1 ]
        },
        {
          "name": "GroupC",
          "indices": [2,3 ]
        }
      ],
    "person": [
        {"name": "Archer"},
        {"name": "Lana"},
        {"name": "Mother"},
        {"name": "Barry"}
      ]
  };

  obj.groups.forEach(g =>  g.person = g.indices.map(i => obj.person[i]))
  console.log(obj.groups)
```

Comment: This mutates the input tho. Could or could not be a problem but with `map` it's never a problem.

Comment: @JohanP Yes, it does. That's how I read the question: 'and then pushing that value to the corresponding object in the 'groups' array.'